# Generate pom.xml for kotlin dsl

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to create `pom.xml` file for all of my project/subproject dependencies. So basically, I want to translate all of my gradle `implementation` to `pom.xml`. For some reason it's not able to find `MavenPluginConvention`

[GroovyReference](https://gist.github.com/jmruc/5852692)

What I tried is this

```
apply {
    plugin("java")
    plugin("maven")
}

task("createPom") {
    group = "maven"
    description = "generates a maven pom.xml file based on the build.gradle.kts file"
    doLast {
        project.the<MavenPluginConvention>().pom() {
            project {
                groupId = "my.group"
                artifactId = "my-app"
                version = "latest"
                withGroovyBuilder {
                    "inceptionYear"("2042")
                }
            }
        }.writeTo("pom.xml")
    }
}
```